# Can I create an Android app similar to a dynamic client server web application?

Tags: android, mysql, servlets, client-server

I am new to Android and taking the risk of doing a final year project of building an Android app. I would like to know whether I can create Client-server architecture application in Android. I'd like the front end to be the mobile app. Also, where do you store data (I don't know where to store data exactly) at back end.

Answer (score 0):

Use Restful web Services with json(Ex: WCF in the backend with Sql Server)
For Mobile App, These are useful tutorials http://developer.android.com/training/index.html,
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html.

Answer (score 0):

Very many, if not most, existing Android apps retrieve data over the Internet and display it (e.g. the StackExchange, Yelp, or Facebook apps). They are clients requesting data from servers and therefore fit into the definition of being “client/server”. I'm hard-pressed to think of an app on my phone that *isn't* a client to some kind of web service.

If, as your question suggests, you are using HTTP for client/server communication, there is no reason why the client platform (Android) should have any impact whatsoever on the server-side implementation. In the wild, Android clients are served by servers implemented with every conceivable combination of OS, language, and database. Therefore “where do you store data?” is an unanswerable question, as the answer depends entirely on implementation choices that you make on the server side.